# ASP Webform and Need Postback When Clicking List Item

Tags: html, asp.net

I have a site master page (Site.Master) that contains a menu of list items to navigate to other pages on my site.  One of those pages is a home page (Default.aspx) that loads up some data from a database.  Whenever I click on the list item for the home page it reloads my entire page because it goes through my not postback logic.  I do not want it to reload my entire page and am not sure how to change my list item in bold below to cause my Default.aspx to not pass through the `if (!IsPostBack)` code below.  What do I need to add to it to cause my Default.aspx page to post back?

Site.Master

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >  
        **<li><a id="A1" runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>**
        <li><a id="A2" runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a id="A3" runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
        <li><a id="A4" runat="server" href="~/Admin">Admin</a></li>             
  </ul>
```

Default.aspx

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
        {            
            //Only do processing that you want to happen on initial load
            SetEnvironment();
            InitializeWebService();
            GetServiceDataSet();
            GetServiceDataSetCopy();
            SetGridViewData();
            SetGridViewAllChecked();
            GetCheckBoxList();                
            LoadReport();
            StoreViewState();
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: There is no preventing this. Just like pressing F5. And I don't see the problem either, every other website in the world works like this. The only thing you could do is remove the link itself.

Comment: @VDWWD is essentially correct,  One way to try and circumvent this is to make your master page link an asp.net control and add logic to it in the master page code behind to handle a case like you are describing

Comment: the above scenario would involve detecting that you are on the default page and essentially not redirect

Comment: Ok, I was hoping to avoid the re-loading of data when going back to my homepage as it takes a little bit for the page to load and there is not a reason why I need to refresh the data every time the home page is hit during the session.  Essentially looking to have it work like the back button on the browser does (which does not cause a refresh of data).  I'll check out maybe handling through code behind, thanks.

Comment: "t takes a little bit for the page to load". Maybe a better use of time would be to try and minimise the load time. Possibly there are things which could be optimised.